# Is it dangerous to use C++ without knowing memory management?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, ram

Is it dangerous to use C++ without knowing memory management?

Is it necessary to know memory management while developing programs in C++ normally? Can we damage computer memory if we don't know it? Or does the program we write inflate/overloading in memory?

Comment: Not related to your question, but you don't need to capitalize every word. It makes it seem like you're 'shouting'.

Comment: In modern `c++` you should never have to use new[] or delete[]

Comment: No, you can't *physically* damage memory, and it's not clear what you mean by "Inflate/Overloading".

Comment: Those are many questions. "dangerous" is also an interpretation, which makes bad SO questions. Lastly, during your own research, what did you find?

Comment: ***Can We Damage Computer Memory If We Don't Know It?*** No your PC RAM is not that fragile. You will not damage your computer by using too much ram or leaking memory ...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "dangerous".  C++ provides a lot of memory management facilities.  A lot of code can be written without worrying about memory management, by the use of classes that encapsulate those memory management details such as `std::string`, or `std::vector`, or `std::unique_ptr`.  Being aware of memory management in C++ is beneficial, to otherwise avoid memory mismanagement.  Most operating systems isolate processes to prevent computer damage by errant programs.  Not sure what "inflate/overloading in memory" means.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it dangerous to use C++ without knowing memory management?

Depends on what you consider "dangerous" and, how willing you are to learn and other factors.

If you attempt to write a program without understanding the language, and without attempting to learn it, then the outcome is likely a program that doesn't work, or one that appears to work but breaks when a seemingly unrelated condition changes.

> Is it necessary to know memory management while developing programs in C++ normally?

It depends.

It's (possibly surprisingly) easy to write even complex programs while avoiding any manual memory management. However, at minimum you must still understand the lifetime of objects which may be considered a basic part of memory management.

Furthermore, if you were to be tasked with developing programs that do involve memory management, then you wouldn't be able to understand it without understanding memory management.

> Can we damage computer memory if we don't know it?

No, not in most cases. Unless you are writing a program that controls a robot arm that can reach and damage its own circuits.